# Why is my mouse lagging over Thunderbird / Firefox window?

Tags: windows, firefox, email, performance, thunderbird

In Thunderbird 31.5.0 I noticed an annoying mouse delay/stutter when mousing over the email list or folder pane.  At the same time I see a CPU spike of about 25% (older WinXP dual core system).

Why is this happening / what can I do to optimize thunderbird for older systems?

( **Update 9/2015**: Also noticed this on Firefox and was able to fix it in about:config using the same layers.acceleration.disabled = true )

Answer (score 3):

There are [two settings in Thunderbirds advanced settings](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2339945) (Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor) that might help this situation:

`layers.acceleration.disabled = true` (defaults to false, this one solved my problem)

`gfx.direct2d.disabled` = true (defaults to false)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point because the default changed in Thunderbird 31. The wiki has more information about it: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Performance_%28Thunderbird%29

Comment: Note: this fix works for Firefox as well!